# how to use complex sql query in EF 4.1 code first

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

We have just started using EF 4.1 code first. I have a sql query something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA  
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(), TableA.ExpirationDate == x days)
```

I don't know how to use sql query with EF 4.1 code first set of functions. One function like this:

```
IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
```

Does anybody has an idea?

Comment: Do you want to convert it into LINQ?
Or you want to preserve the pure SQL Query, if so you Eranga example that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<EntityA>("SELECT * FROM TableA
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(), TableA.ExpirationDate == x days");
```

Comment: @alice7 `DbContext`. If you are using `ObjectContext` use the `ExecuteStoreQuery` method.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this is close to your query:

```
var things = context.TableAEntities
    .Where(e => EntityFunctions.DiffDays(DateTime.Now, e.ExpirationDate) == x)
    .ToList();
```

It translates to:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
//... more columns
[Extent1].[ExpirationDate] AS [ExpirationDate]
FROM [dbo].[TableA] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (DATEDIFF (day, SysDateTime(), [Extent1].[ExpirationDate])) = @p__linq__0
```

`SysDateTime()` (in SQL Server) is the same as `GETDATE()`, it just has a higher precision.

Comment: +1 for `EntityFunctions`, I have been using EF code-first since the 4.0 CTP and had no idea they existed, definitely going to look more into them now.